# Stopping user to change values in html source before submitting form

Tags: html, browser, client-side

I have a simple html form as follows:

```
<form action="Test">
    <select name="mySelect">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
        <option value="4">Four</option>
        <option value="5">Five</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Following is my `servlet` code to read the value of select in get method:

```
System.out.println("Value of select: "+ request.getParameter("mySelect"));
```

This works fine, until I change the value from inspect element option. After changing the value from inspect element, and submitting the form, it sends `Test` as a value of `Two` instead of 2, to `servlet`, which is not expected.

[image]

My question is that, Is there any way we can avoid this issue? or How to prevent client from sending incorrect data?

Comment: At this point I see nothing here that would actually -cause- this to happen. What magical piece of logic is changing the value to Test?

Comment: Well this is a normal behaviour... just don't do it, but don't ever forget the user can submit anything he wants.

Comment: Are you asking how to prevent client from sending you incorrect data? If so then answer is "you can't", that is why server side needs to have validation mechanisms.

Comment: @Pshemo yes, I meant exactly that

Comment: @Bhushan Unfortunately, we can't :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing stopping a user from changing values in browser by using firebug/inspect element/ what ever..

What we can do is checking our values on server side and prompting user if they mismatch.

Shouting again ..

## Never trust/depend on client....

Answer (score 0):

You can disable right click and the F12 button to prevent the issue.
Follow the below links.

1.) Disable right click
2.) Disable F12 button